# React native android app is showing blank white screen after building

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

[image]

In the above image, you can see that the app has been built successfully and has started the metro bundler.

[image]

If I try to click on **R**, It is saying that no device is connected even though the app is running on an emulator.

[image]

The above is the screen I'm seeing once the building completes and the app is opened. A blank white screen.

Below is my **index.js** file

```
import "expo-asset";
import { AppRegistry, View } from "react-native";
import App from "./App";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by manually creating a bundle using the following command on the root of the project

```
npx mkdirp android/app/src/main/assets/ && npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```